# Batch file help please: If exist C:\Program Files\Adobe OR C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

How can I modify the following batch file to check both `C:\Program Files\Adobe` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe`?

This code only looks for `C:\Program Files\Adobe`

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files\Adobe" goto end
echo %computername% > \\server001\share\%computername%.txt
:end
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
@echo off
If exist "C:\Program Files\Adobe" If exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe" goto end
echo %computername% > \\server001\share\%computername%.txt
:end
```

Your help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this way?

```
@echo off
If exist "C:\Program Files\Adobe"       goto end
If exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe" goto end
echo %computername% > \\server001\share\%computername%.txt
:end
```

Comment: Imagine, `"C:\Program Files\Adobe"` or `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe"` are files. Then this will also be `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files\Adobe" goto end
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe" goto end
echo %computername% > \\server001\share\%computername%.txt
:end
```

This is the most simple way. Will `goto end` if either or both directories exist.

If you want to always check for both:

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files\Adobe" (
  if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe" (
    goto end
  )
)
echo %computername% > \\server001\share\%computername%.txt
:end
```

This will only `goto end` if both directories exist.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal 
If exist "C:\Program Files\Adobe\" (goto:end) else If exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\" goto:end
```

If you test for folders, you should better put a backslash at the end. Otherwise this can also be true if you have a file with this name.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely not a single command to work in both OS. You have to check in both the places:

```
SET ProgFiles86Root=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
IF NOT "%ProgFiles86Root%"=="" GOTO win64
SET ProgFiles86Root=%ProgramFiles%
:win64

"%ProgFiles86Root%\name of program" "arguments, etc."
```